# Reliable and fast Git GUI for OSX

Tags: osx, gui, git

I'm looking for a Git GUI for OSX.

I've previously used Tower, SourceTree and GitBox. My problem with these are:

- Tower gets slow and is prone to crashes when working on large projects.
- SourceTree doesn't always accurately show unstaged files/staged changes to commit. Restarting the app will fix this, but until the bug is fixed I really don't want to use it.
- GitBox didn't give me the control I wanted.

Beside that, I do like Tower and SourceTree. But I really want to find a faster and more friction-less alternative. I don't mind paid apps.